# Shrink Webview Content width to fit the screen

Tags: android, webview

Im trying to shrink the width content of my webview down to fit with my screen so i dont have to scroll side way anymore...i tried so many code but it still doesnt anyone have any idea how??

heres my code so far.

```
    postView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.postView);
    postView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    postView.setInitialScale((int) .8);
    WebSettings settings = postView.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Comment: I think your call to setInitialScale() isn't doing what you expect.  This should be a whole number like 80 to get 80% scaling.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can define width of webview with screenwidth itself and add it to its param section.

```
int screenWidth = getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
postView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    screenWidth / 2, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
/*I have assumed your webview's parent is tablerow. You must define layout params with respect to its parent. like if postview parentview is linearlayout then new LinearLayout.LayoutParams() must be used*/
```

This must solve your problem.

Hope, this helps.

**Edit**

Ok, now I get your problem. But I think in your case you should allow the user to get zoom in/out , so that user will get control for data he wants to view.

Add this statement

```
postView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: your code basically shrinking my Webview instead of shrinking the Webview's Content, the content inside my webview is still overflow the webview =(..

Comment: lols i wud  +1 your answer bro...but i need 15 repution...>_>..i only have 11 :(

Comment: you dont have to +1 the answer, Just tick the answer mark to mark the question as answered. You don't need any reputation points to do so. [Just follow this link for clarity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/221351)

Comment: Why screenWidth / 2 and not just screenWidth?