# Zooming an Image view in android with a URL as a String

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom, imageurl

I was getting the url as a string and i am appending it to images properly and they were able to display. Now I need to Pinch zoom that image by any way i.e. double click, pinch zoom and taking it to another activity....

I found links but they are local drawables but i need for urls

Comment: what is difference? if it works what you found for local, just download image and put it there.

Comment: I was able to download the image by lazylist but i cant zoom it.Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following links. May this help you

1. https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView
2. http://blahti.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/pan-zoom-examples-for-android/
3. http://www.wglxy.com/android-tutorials/android-touch-pan-and-zoom-examples

Comment: Thanks a lot touchimageview helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of below library, that will work with `Activity`, `Fragment`, `RecylerView`.

https://github.com/rahulkapoor1/ZommableLoadingImageView

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your question..

Do you want pinch zoom functionality in `ImageView` that you are using. then [refer this link](http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/02/pinch-zoom-on-imageview.html)

Or

is it you are using an `WebView` to load your image from url and want zoom_in_out functionality in `WebView` then use

```
.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

[link for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392517/2345913)

If thats not what you want then let me know..

Comment: I added ZoomableImageView to my project it shows no errors but how to make my imageview to be zoomable and it is not a bitmap. I was getting a url string

Comment: Im confused. you are using `ZoomableImageView` and you want to load image through url, is that what u want,, then Why not go with WebView instead of ImageView., see my post if that can be helpful..

Comment: by webview I cant see any image. But I found solution from [link](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)